# I have a query in JAVA regarding f/d

Tags: java

Why do we use f/d at the time of initialization of a `float`/`double` variable in **JAVA**?
Eg.,

```
float var1 = 8.56f;
double var2 = 0.87654d;
```

Will that increase the speed of compilation? Or what maybe the exact reason?

Comment: No, it's just part of a Java numeric literal syntax. There is no need to use literal qualifiers when assigning to a variable where you specified the type already. It will be needed to assign to some general variable, such as `Number o = 1.032f`.

Comment: You should step back ... and first get clear on very fundamental things. I guess you don't mean "speed of compilation" ... but runtime performance. Which are two completely different things.

Comment: suppose if you declare a variable like this

    `float f = 3.14; // give compiler error.`

Because, compiler thinks that your trying to assign the `double` 3.14 to `float` without type casting.

You can do this way also, like below line without f letter.

    `float f = (float)3.14; //compiles fine`

But in case of double it is not necessary the letter `d`. 

    `double d = 3.14;`

Comment: Ohh that sounds great ....THANK YOU GUYS..i got my doubt clarified from your answers.

Answer (score 1):

For doubles and float, you need to specify the compiler the type of the input.
Initiailizing 10.0 to a float variable would bring nothing but ambiguity to the compiler, as it would not understand if the value is float or a double.

So by specifying f/d at the end of the value, you're actually removing the ambiguity for the complier by using these format specifiers.